# Parameterised stored proc

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm writing a parameterized stored proc. I know that you can set the parameter value such that it displays all the results when the parameter is not mentioned in the execute command.. But i'm unable to recall how that is achieved. Any help is highly appreciated... Please..

Comment: A conditional statement is needed in the query, but it's not recommended to be done in a single query -- not sargable.

Comment: I think there is a way where you can set the default value of the parameter as NULL or something which will let me exec the stored procedure without using parameters.. do I make sense.. I don't know..

Comment: @OMG Ponies depending on how it's written you can make it sargable using `OPTION RECOMPILE`, no?

Comment: @Matthew PK: Throwing away the query plan every time does **not** make a query sargable.  You want that query plan cache - the problem with conditional statements is the query can be different each time, so you get the behavior of `OPTION RECOMPILE` without using the keywords.

Comment: See Gail Shaw's blog post on [Catch-all queries](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/).

Comment: @OMG Ponies, Erland Sommarskog indicates that forcing the recompile will evaluate the parameters as literals, which can make it sargable... unless I have misunderstood him

Comment: @Matthew PK: Got link?  I don't see how throwing out the query plan changes the fact the query can/will change

Comment: @OMG Ponies http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html#static scroll to **Static SQL** section to find "SQL Server will use the actual variable values as if they were constants."

Comment: @Matthew PK: Cool, thx - will read.  I'm not strong on 2008+ specific stuff.

Comment: @OMG Ponies according to Erland it actually only works in SP1+ It's not every day that somebody points a DB feature out to OMG Ponies :D

Comment: @Matthew PK: That's part of my concern -- the OP hasn't said if using SQL Server or Sybase, or version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `WHERE` conditions like this:

```
WHERE (@myParam IS NULL OR @myParam = someValue)
```

You may be able to use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is SQL2008SP1+ (or similar, don't know other options) in the sproc, depending on your RDBMS, to get this to be performant.

Method from Erland Sommarskog:
http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html#static

**From the link**:
"The effect of all the @x IS NULL clauses is that if that input parameter is NULL, then that AND-condition is always true. Thus, the only conditions that are in effect are those where the search parameter has a non-NULL value.

As far as maintainability goes, it's difficult to think of a better solution for the search conditions at hand. It's compact, easy to read and to extend. And performance? Very good as long as you include the query hint OPTION (RECOMPILE). This hint forces the query to be recompiled each time, in which case SQL Server will use the actual variable values as if they were constants."

Comment: You mean something like        Create Proc USP_MyStoreProc Where @MyParam is NULL

Comment: @Avinash I don't understand your comment. I'm talking about how you *use* the parameters inside the sproc.

Comment: Well.. Its simple store proc with a select statement and checks if one of the columns matches the parameter in the Where clause. In addition I want to display all the results if none of them match..

Comment: @Avinash why don't you post the select in your question and I'll try to adapt it for you?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend parameterized dynamic sql ([sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx))

Going this route, you can discard any irrelevant parameter when building your where clause.

Example procedure:

```
create proc dbo.SearchForStuff
(
 @Id int = 0
,@Description varchar(100) = ''
)
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    declare @select nvarchar(max) = '
    select
    s.*
    from Stuff as s'

    declare @where varchar(max) = ''

    if isnull(@ID,0) != 0 begin                 
        set @where += case @where when '' then ' where ' else ' and ' end + 's.Id = @Id'        
    end

    if isnull(@Description,'') != '' begin      
        set @where +=  case @where when '' then ' where ' else ' and ' end + 's.[Description] = @Description'       
    end         

    set @select += @where

    exec sp_executesql
     @select
    ,N'
    ,@Id int = 0
    ,@Description varchar(100) = '''''
    ,@Id
    ,@Description      

end
```

Usage:

```
exec SearchForStuff @Id = 1, @Description = 'omg' -- Returns every item where Id is 1 and Description is 'omg'
exec SearchForStuff @Id = 1  -- Returns every item where Id is 1
exec SearchForStuff @Description = 'omg' -- Returns every item where Description is 'omg'
exec SearchForStuff --returns every item
```

In this fashion your final query is not littered with useless conditions. Further, you can get a bit more granular than I did here. Based upon which parameters were passed, you can tailor your where/join clauses to take advantage of your indexes such that you get the best possible performance. The only drawback is a *slight* loss of readability (imo).

Answer (score 1):

If it is an `int` you can use

```
SELECT X,Y
FROM T
WHERE C BETWEEN COALESCE(@P, -2147483648) AND COALESCE(@P, 2147483647)
```

[The definitive article on the subject](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)