# dynamic column name in where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
declare @temp varchar(20)
declare @name varchar(20)
set @name = 'John'
set @temp  = 'e'
select * from TableA
    where   case when @temp = 'e' then [em_name]
          case when @temp = 'c' then [company_name] 
        end
          = @name
```

This query is giving me error(A non-Boolean expression in where clause).

Please explain what is wrong in this query and how can i achieve this without dynamic sql.

so when i give `@temp  = 'C'` then it should search for `[company_name] = @name`. and have a long list of `@temp values(employee name, company name, city name, state name, supervisor name etc)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterised stored proc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916748/parameterised-stored-proc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the snip you posted:

```
where   case when @temp = 'e' then [em_name]
      case when @temp = 'c' then [company_name] 
    end
      = @name
```

Should be:

```
WHERE CASE WHEN @temp = 'e' THEN em_name
        WHEN @temp = 'c' THEN company_name 
    END = @name
```

Note there is now only one CASE keyword. Here's the more common syntax (for completeness):

```
DECLARE @temp VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(20)
SET @name = 'John'
SET @temp = 'e'

SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE (@temp = 'e' AND [em_name] = @name)
    OR (@temp = 'c' AND [company_name] = @name)
```

Comment: This approach is good but the query is used in 6 places in a SP. Each place, the where part would have 7 OR clauses (which would look messy). The case statements where legible. I took it from     http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic717900-338-1.aspx But the query is giving errors.

Comment: I'm not sure if 7 WHEN clauses would be more or less messy, but other maintainers will probably be less familiar with it. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Jake. The Case statement now works fine. In the other option(OR), the variable @name occurs too many times, and this CASE goes with certain other where clause-conditions. This gave the braces complexity. Now the case is perfectly readable and sits perfectly along with certain other clauses..

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE (@temp = 'e' AND [em_name] = @name) OR (@temp = 'c' AND [company_name] = @name)
```